# How to Access inputRef values in MaterialUI/React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to access DOM elements similarly to getElementById with useRef.  I declare my variable like so and this is my Texfield:

```
const inputRefAmount = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);


            <TextField
                inputRef={inputRefAmount}
                value={amount}
                id="output_elevator-amount"
                label="Elevator amount"
                color='primary'
                type="number"
                InputLabelProps={{
                  shrink: true,
                }}
                InputProps={{
                  readOnly: true,
                }}
                onChange={serviceCalc}
                />
            <TextField
```

In a function I would like to use the ref to manipulate it, something like this(which does not work)

```
const standard = () => {
    console.log("returns standard")
    
    let elevatorAmt = inputRefAmount.current
    console.log(elevatorAmt)
    let unitPrice = 7565;
    let installFee = (unitPrice * parseInt(elevatorAmt.value)) * 0.1;
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

According to the provided code, it seems you are using ref to receive the value of `TextField` rather than manipulate it.
In case you need to value, you should use your `amount` state.

Here are some use cases for refs according to React [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs):

> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.

[Here's](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/useeffect-vs-uselayouteffect) another good read about useEffect & useLayoutEffect, hooks that are used along useRef almost always.

Comment: thanks for your reply! when you say use amount state, can I import the component and use the value amount in another file?

Comment: @user17710829 If I understand your question correctly, yes, you can achieve it if the value is passed as a prop to another component or as an argument to some calculation function